# Следует ли мне изучать математику на англоязычных сайтах?

Tags: машинное-обучение, big-data, искусственный-интеллект

Намерен стать дата-сатанистом, нашел что за бугром математика преподается лучше, да и выбор больше, например khan academy. Английский знаю отлично, сейчас учусь в 11 классе. Вопрос - будут ли у меня потом проблемы связанные с переходом между 2-мя языками?

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, кто вам сказал, что забугорный автоматический бездушный видосик обучит вас математике лучше, чем живой учитель?

Во-вторых, обучение вообще -  и математике в частности - зависит не от того, на каком языке вы учитесь, а от того, как вы самостоятельно учите то, что вам рассказывают. А в математике - еще сильно и от ваших способностей, которые от языка преподавания вообще не зависят.

В-третьих, учите хоть на китайском, главное, что-бы потом вы не сказали, что вас плохо научили потому что вы не все понимали на чужом языке.

И наконец, а какие проблемы у вас могут быть, если вы знаете язык "отлично" (Хотя, конечно, данный критерий очень субъективен, и что такое "отлично" кажды понимает по-своему).